# Connecting to SQL Server database no opening MVC 4

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble connecting to my database to run a query. Here us the connection and query info:

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Webs\\MvcFFL\\MvcFFL\\App_Data\\Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        string queryString =  "Truncate table Players;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

    connection.Open(); <- Fails here opening the connection

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why this is failing to open the connection. This is using SQL Server. I have this declared at the top:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Comment: userid and password missing

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad userid and password missing IF there are existing.

Comment: @kostasch. what are you trying to say?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad He means that LocalDB like OP is using may not require a user a pass combination.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad that if you don't have set you do not need to put them in the connection string. If you use trasted security and so on

Comment: my connection information in the web.config file does not include a user name or password. here is the connection info for the web.config file `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcFFL-20140517174741;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcFFL-20140517174741.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> <add name="PlayerDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Players.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your connection string, @user3240928 , What is the exact error you are getting when your code fails?

Comment: Gotta let us know what errors you're getting.  make sure the file exists as well c:\Webs\MvcFFL\MvcFFL\App_Data\Players.mdf

Comment: Here is the error: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: So if i turn off integrated security then it should work?

Comment: I have tried turning off intergrated security and that did not work, i cannot connect to the localdb in sql server Management studio. Does anybody else know why i can connect using that query above?